# This week Internet Explorer started giving me errors with Jquery where it worked fine before

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

My code was working fine in Internet Explorer until this week.  It works fine in Chrome.  I haven't made any changes to the code.  I now get this error:

```
SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined.
```

Here is the code up to the point where I get the error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Victoria Traffic</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Victoria Traffic Incidents. Press F5 to update.</h1>
        <div id="placeholder"></div>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $.getJSON ...(more code here)
```

What is going on that I am now getting this error?

Comment: You should post the whole script.

Comment: Most probably, `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js` is failing to download.

Comment: If you haven't changed any code have you changed the version on IE that you are using?

Comment: It's IE 11.0.960.17105. The only update has been the recent security update, not a major update.

Comment: What browser mode and document mode is the site loading in?

Comment: This isn't an answer (hence the comment form), but if you have the developer tools open in IE, start recording the network requests. See if the request for jquery is even made and succeeds. If it does, maybe try moving the script request up to the <head> just to see if there's something weird going on with how it's loading.

Comment: I suspect alex may be close to the answer.  Although I'm not sure why this would be the case for IE only.  My best guess at the moment is that the admin may have remotely changed the security policy.

Comment: The browser is downloading jquery (92.01kb).

Comment: I believe the browser is in it's default configuration in regards to the browser and document modes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system administrators remotely disabled java-script on the windows domain while patching for the latest vulnerabilities.  Hopefully they will be done soon.

Answer (score 0):

Try also including a JSON library in your page like this one:

```
<script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
```

Or alternately, [download a copy of json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) from GitHub.